# Write to multiple excel sheets at same time

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I have a script which creates an excel workbook with two worksheets, the script formats cells, etc. in `sheet1` however I also want to do the same formatting in `sheet2`. Is there an easy way to do the formatting to both sheets at the same time instead of making a full copy of what is done for `sheet1` and doing for `sheet2` also.
Below is some of the code i have and want to do for both sheets

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(outFileXLSX)                           
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Results 1') 
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Results 2')     
sheet1 = worksheet1    
sheet2 = worksheet2 

sheet1.merge_range('A1:A4', '', format_header)                         
sheet1.merge_range('B1:B4', 'Merged Range', format_header)
```

The two lines above i need to do also in `sheet2`
Any help or advise would be great

Comment: for s in [sheet1,sheet2]:

Comment: WNG - new to python can you elaborate further how to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Turn the repeated steps into a function and pass in the parameters, so something like:

```
def do_stuff(workbook, names):
    '''
    Call this function with the workbook reference and a sequence of sheet names
    '''
    for sheet in names:  # this will do the following for each name in the sequence
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet)
        worksheet.merge_range('A1:A4', '', format_header)                         
        worksheet.merge_range('B1:B4', 'Merged Range', format_header)
        # any other stuff you want to do to each worksheet


# Here is your main block now...
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(outFileXLSX)                           
do_stuff(workbook, ['Results 1', 'Results 2'])
```

Comment: Docstring needs to be indented.